# Attempting to allow keyboard/letter scroll in boostrap dropdown rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, keyboard-events

I am building a rails app and have a Constituency model which has 500+ entries - my Index page has a dropdown menu which includes the links to the show pages for each of these but I can't figure out how to allow users to navigate through the dropdown by typing the letters on the keyboard (e.g. hitting z would move the dropdown to constituencies begining with z). Seems like it should be simple but have been looking for ages and not found a working solution. I have attempted a jquery-based alternative but this works once in a session but does not respond when returning to the index page... Any help much appreciated!!

Dropdown menu using Bootstrap/Ruby:

```
     <div class="btn-group"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Go to your Constituency... <span class="caret"></span></button><ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" role="menu">
        <% @constituencies.each do |constituency| %>
        <li><a:focus>
          <%= link_to constituency.name, constituency %></a>
        </li>
         <% end %>
      </ul>
         </div> 
    </div>
```

jquery alternative (only working first time around):

```
  $(function(){
      $('#constituencies_id').bind('change', function {
        var url = "/constituencies/" + $(this).val()
         if (url) {
          window.location = (url);
      }
      return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can go about this. Here are just three.

### Live Filter

How about having a filter? [I just wrote one the other day](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/85954/vanilla-javascript-live-filter). Add a text field to the dropdown. As the user types, filter the dropdown items. Set a fixed height on the dropdown so that you can limit its height and allow vertical scrolling in the event of many dozens of items.

This approach is suitable for small data sets, maybe 50 items or so. I wouldn't recommend it for more because:

1. Hundreds of items in a dropdown is bad UX design.
2. Memory. Loading 500 AR objects into memory to display the dropdown isn't always a good idea. Although you can use caching to mitigate this.
3. Template compile time. Again, rendering 500 partials, or 500 fragments may not be ideal. Again, you can use fragment caching to mitigate this.
4. Performance on mobile devices. If the user is using a mobile device, this could slow things down considerably.

### Remote Live Filter

This is nearly the same as the above, but instead of loading all items before hand, you show a small subset of results, maybe the most popular. But when the user types a search query, instead of filtering on the client side, make an ajax request and fetch results that match the search query. This adds some complexity, but it solves most of the problems outlined in the first approach.

### JavaScript Rendering with a Live Filter

Almost the same as option one, but instead of rendering the dropdown on the server, return JSON to the client, and use a JS framework, like ReactJS, or plain Javascript to build the dropdown after the page is loaded.

As you can see, there are many ways to solve this. You have to choose the right approach that best meets the requirements of your app.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am not familiar with using filters - is this the only solution do you think? My JS approach above works but only the first time in a session for some reason..

Comment: It could be because of Turbolinks, which prevents the `document.ready` event from firing when transitioning between pages, so the event handler never gets bound again until you do a page refresh.

Comment: @MathDaniel You must bind the event handler on Turbolinks' events (if user clicks a Turbolink to get to the page), as well as `document.ready` (if page is refreshed, or user lands on page directly). Here's a quick example I wrote: https://gist.github.com/abitdodgy/ff713f19aaed488a3628